# Do I need to buy Pardot to practice what I learn about it or is there a free version like developer orgs?

Tags: pardot, b2b-commerce, b2b

I am trying to lean Pardot for a future project purpose, but I am not finding any way of testing what I will learn in future. I do not have a salesforce premium account, is there a way to test and practice its features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no free/developer accounts for pardot and marketing clouds, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Only Salesforce partners can request a Pardot training environment. Go to the [Pardot B2B Marketing Automation Group](http://p.force.com/PardotGroup) in the partner community and submit the form in the information section.

Take a look at below learning references

https://www.pardot.com/marketing-inspiration/trailhead-the-fun-way-to-learn-pardot/
https://automationchampion.com/pardot/

Thanks